# What do the different characters mean in an OrigenLink log file?

Tags: origen-sdk

In the OrigenLink log files I see things like this:

```
P:001.`
P:000.`
P:011.`
P:011.`
```

I understand that `P:` means that the vector/cycle passed and then we are seeing the pin values, but what do the dot and backtick characters mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The responses from the link server are:

P: - Pass (no failures on this cycle)

F: - Fail

W: - Warning (forces failure)

The next group of characters describe what action was performed per pin:

0 - drove DUT pin low

1 - drove DUT pin high

H - read logic 1 from DUT (and performed Pass/Fail comparison)

L - read logic 0 from DUT (and performed Pass/Fail comparison)

` - read logic 1 from DUT (no P/F comparison - vector data was X)

. - read logic 0 from DUT (no P/F comparison - vector data was X)

You can find more here: http://origen-sdk.org/OrigenLink/api/OrigenLink/Server/Pin.html#process_event-instance_method